# Mule Dataweave - Converting XML to JSON List with Multiple Object types

Tags: mule, mule-studio, dataweave, mule-esb

I have to convert a XML payload to JSON. The challenge here is the order of XML should not be changed while we convert it into JSON list of multiple type of objects ( Single JSON list has multiple object types).

Comment: Be precise. Post sample input and output.

Comment: Please also post what you've tried so far and the results.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON will output in the order that you specify in your Dataweave transform. Just make sure that your output is in the order that you want and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

First use https://codebeautify.org/xmltojson to convert your xml to json and save it in json format. now use this file as metadata. your xml will be convert same to json.